# Convert Symmetrix Matrix into Lower Triangular Matrix

Tags: format-conversion, scipy, distance-matrix, megax, pdist

I'm using Scipy's pdist function to calculate a distance matrix which is working great but it gives me a symmetric matrix and I want to convert it into a lower-left triangular matrix.

This is what it prints out for me:

```
  a   b   c   d
a 0 ### ### ###
b ### 0 ### ###
c ### ### 0 ###
d ### ### ### 0
```

This is what I want it to be:

```
###
### ###
### ### ###
```

I know there's a function in R to do this (upper.tri) but it just replaces everything to the right of the 0 with more 0s. Is there a better/easier way to get it like this? I'm opening the file in excel and removing everything to the right with the 0 manually right now.

Comment: From reading the scipy documentation for the [`pdist` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist), it seems to suggest it should already only return upper-triangular entries rather than a full matrix. Are you using `pdist` directly or through some other package?

Comment: This is the command I use to calculate the distance: `pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(kmer_matrix, 'euclidean')))` I convert it into a pandas dataframe so it's easier to output into a file and I use squareform because I read somewhere that it helps space out the final output.

Comment: I just tried running it without `squareform` and it outputs all the distances in a descending list :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NumPy has a convenient built-in function for accessing the lower-triangular or upper-trianglar entries of an array.
To get the lower-triangular entries, you can use [`numpy.tril_indices`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html)
to get the indices of these entries, and then use these indices to extract the entries.

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array(
    [[0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8]]
)
idx = np.tril_indices(3, -1)
ar[idx]
# outputs array([3, 6, 7])
```

This doesn't automatically produce the spacing you want, but formatting the final display is likely context-dependent.

Comment: This could work for now thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a scipy method that retains the lower triangle but with the 0s. See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.tril.html#scipy.sparse.tril

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty helpful too